# Test the convergence of the following series depending on real parameters a and b

Tags: sequences-and-series

Our [task](https://ibb.co/mt87fSf) is to find for which $a$ and $b$ the following series converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sqrt{n+a}- \sqrt[4]{n^2 + n + b}\right)$$ I find that $b$ does not matter, (it can be any number). But I can not find what parameter $a$ should be.

In solution it says that parameter $a$ supposed to be $1/2$, but I do not know how to get that.

Can someone explain to me how to get parameter $a$?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you showed how you deduced that $b$ was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}\right)\frac{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}}=\frac{n+a-\sqrt{n^2+n+b}}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}}=$$

$$=\frac{(n+a)^2-n^2-n-b}{\left(\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}\right)\left(n+a+\sqrt{n^2+n+b}\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(2a-1)n-b}{\left(\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+n+b}\right)\left(n+a+\sqrt{n^2+n+b}\right)}\;\;(**)$$

The above is asymptotically equal to

$$\frac{(2a-1)n}{\sqrt n\cdot n}=(2a-1)\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

and thus the series cannot converge... **unless** $\;2a-1=0\iff a=\cfrac12\;$ and then $\;(**)\;$ is asymptotic to $\;\cfrac1{n^{3/2}}\;$ and convergent. Indeed, $\;b\;$ is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt {n+a} -\sqrt [4] {n^{2}+n+b}=\sqrt n [ \sqrt {1+\frac a n} -\sqrt [4] {1+\frac 1 n+\frac b {n^{2}}}]$. This is $\sqrt n [1+\frac a {2n} -(1+\frac 1 4 (\frac 1 n))+0(\frac1 {n^{2}})]$. Hence the convergence of the given series is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_n \sqrt n (\frac a 2 -\frac 1 4) \frac 1 n$. Clearly, this series converges only when $\frac a 2 -\frac 1 4=0$ or $a =\frac 1 2$.